# AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

When I used selenium, I tried to use find_element_by_**** function, but apparently it doesn't exist.

I tried this (XPATH is just an example):

```
driver.find_element_by_XPATH('********')
```

But python told me this: "AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'".

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your Selenium must me >= `Selenium 4.3.0` that is the reason you are getting this error:

`"AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'`"

Selenium 4.3.0

> Deprecated find_element_by_* and find_elements_by_* are now removed (#10712)

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/a4995e2c096239b42c373f26498a6c9bb4f2b3e7/py/CHANGES

Try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=''********'')
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace 'your_xpath_expression_here' with the XPath expression you want to use to locate the element.

If you are trying to use a different method, make sure to use the correct method name and syntax for the type of element locator you are using (e.g., find_element_by_id, find_element_by_name, find_element_by_link_text, etc.).

here:----

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('your_xpath_expression_here')
```